# Redux-Persist dont save state after update

Tags: javascript, reactjs, redux, persist

Redux-persist dont save redux-store after update. It save to the localStorage only initialState, then dont update with actual data again.
In Redux DevTools i can see some info about rehydrate action with initialState
[Redux DevTools](https://i.stack.imgur.com/gHT5m.png)

configureStore.ts

```
import { applyMiddleware, createStore, compose } from 'redux';
import { composeWithDevTools } from 'redux-devtools-extension';
import createSagaMiddleware from 'redux-saga';
import storage from 'redux-persist/lib/storage'; // localStorage
// import storage from 'localforage';
import { persistStore, persistReducer } from 'redux-persist';
import { createFilter } from 'redux-persist-transform-filter';
// import hardSet from 'redux-persist/lib/stateReconciler/hardSet';
import createReducer from './reducers';

export const persistConfig = {
  key: 'root',
  storage,
  version: 2,
};

const sagaMiddleware = createSagaMiddleware();
const middlewares = [sagaMiddleware];

const enhancers = [applyMiddleware(...middlewares)];

const persistedReducer = persistReducer(persistConfig, createReducer());

export default (initialState = {}) => {
  const store: any = createStore(persistedReducer, initialState, composeWithDevTools(...enhancers));
  const persistor = persistStore(store);

  store.runSaga = sagaMiddleware.run;
  store.injectedReducers = {}; // Reducer registry
  store.injectedSagas = {}; // Saga registry

  if (module.hot) {
    module.hot.accept('./reducers', () => {
      store.replaceReducer(createReducer(store.injectedReducers));
    });
  }

  return { store, persistor };
};
```

app.ts

```
import React from 'react';
import ReactDOM from 'react-dom';
import 'sanitize.css/sanitize.css';
import { Provider } from 'react-redux';
import { Router } from 'react-router';
import { PersistGate } from 'redux-persist/integration/react';
import App from './containers/App';
import configureStore from '../utils/configureStore';
import { history } from '../appHistory';
import 'semantic-ui-css/semantic.min.css';

const initialState = {};
const { store, persistor } = configureStore(initialState);

ReactDOM.render(
  <Provider store={store}>
    <PersistGate loading={null} persistor={persistor}>
      <Router history={history}>
        <App />
      </Router>
    </PersistGate>
  </Provider>,
  document.getElementById('root'),
);
```

And createReducer here

```
import { combineReducers } from 'redux';

export default function createReducer(injectedReducers = {}) {
  return combineReducers({
    ...injectedReducers,
  });
}
```

Version of deps:
"redux-persist": "^6.0.0-pre2.1",
"redux": "^4.1.0",
"react-redux": "^7.2.4",

Comment: Could the issue be that your hot reload functionality replaces the reducer with a non-`persistReducer` reducer?

Comment: Comment the hot reload code didnt help

Comment: New info. Redux-Persist dont save async reducers at all. 
The last save of this reduces was when i spicified it in combineReducers like this:
  
return combineReducers({
    selfRegistration: selfRefReducer,
    ...injectedReducers,
  });